# Inlining and static function call operators

Tags: c++, templates, inline, functor

I have a function template parameterized by a template parameter `T` to give it different behavior depending on what `T` it is instantiated with. The specific  variations desired are very simple, a call to a static function `T::foo(some_args)` would suffice, because no state is involved.

However I do not want to that `foo` to appear in the body of the function template.

I would rather call `T(some_args);`to avoid syntactic noise. I believe declaring the function call operator `()` to be static is not possible (or is it ?). `T` has no state, therefore no instance specific variables.

In the event the above is not possible, what has more chance of getting inlined / optimized (in G++, Clang, ICC)

```
T::foo(some_args); // foo being a static function
```

or

```
T()(some_args);  // operator () declared inline
```

I dont know assembly to check the output, and the question is more from an academic/curiosity point of view than actual performance.

Does `T()(some_args)` really allocate an object at runtime ? or is it typically optimized away ?

Comment: Try it at different optimization levels, and look at the generated assembler code. It will tell you if the object creation has been optimized away or not. My guess is not, since you're invoking a function on an instance instead of a static function.

Comment: What you ask seems rather strange. `T` should have `operator()` defined if it acts as a functor. If that's the case, just pass an instance (even a temporary) to the function, like a regular functor. If it's not a functor, there is no syntactic noise in calling `foo`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg as I have mentioned in my question I dont know assembly to figure that out. So any simple demo will be nice.

Comment: @Alex Yes, could you read my question again. It involves syntactic noise for one option and a potential temporary in another. For the latter I am asking if it will get optimized away.

Comment: Just curious that why do you consider `foo()` inside the body of the function, as a *syntactic noise*?

Comment: @iammilind because the `T` itself is sufficient to describe the variation, so foo is a) unnecessary and b) for all T one has to have a named function `foo` that too is unnecessary

Comment: @san if `T` has no members and an empty constructor, creating a local variable on the stack is typically a single instruction that takes just 1 CPU cycle. Furthermore, this single instruction usually allocates the space for ALL local variables at once, so it is highly unlikely (read: next to impossible) to feel any performance drop from creating an instance.

Comment: @Alex thats good to know, in my case it might still be measurable, as this will get invoked for every scalar lookup in a matrix vector multiply_esque function. Probably go with T::foo() then, atleast looks prettier than T()(). Strange why () is not allowed to be static.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example:

```
struct T
{
    int operator()(int i) const {
        return i+1;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    return T()(1);
}
```

Compiled with -O2 this will yield:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x0000000000400400 <+0>:     mov    eax,0x2
   0x0000000000400405 <+5>:     ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Even with -O0 this will not create a temporary in case you use the implicit default constructor in T:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main():
   0x00000000004004ec <+0>:     push   rbp
   0x00000000004004ed <+1>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x00000000004004f0 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x00000000004004f4 <+8>:     lea    rax,[rbp-0x1]
   0x00000000004004f8 <+12>:    mov    esi,0x1
   0x00000000004004fd <+17>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000000000400500 <+20>:    call   0x400508 <T::operator()(int) const>
   0x0000000000400505 <+25>:    leave
   0x0000000000400506 <+26>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```